# What does "DB::Exception: RangeReader read 7523 rows, but 7550 expected" exception mean in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM reporting_events WHERE (device_id = 51);
```

Result:

```
DB::Exception: RangeReader read 7523 rows, but 7550 expected..
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE reporting_events (
  id UInt64,
  a UInt32,
  b UInt64,
  c UInt32,
  d DEFAULT 0,
  e UInt32 DEFAULT 0,
  device_id UInt32,
  ts DateTime DEFAULT now(),
  name String,
  type Enum8('ONLINE'      = 0,
             'OFFLINE'     = 1,
             'INFORMATION' = 2,
             'WARNING'     = 3,
             'CRITICAL'    = 4),
  description String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(ts)
ORDER BY (a, b, e, device_id, ts, type)
TTL ts + INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

Clickhouse version 20.1.3.7.

Comment: Dmitriy, could you add the reference to your github-issue? thanks

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8964

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CH bug. And now it is fixed since 20.1.5 version - https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/8964